# The “lang” attribute changed my font settings in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, fonts

For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="zh-cn">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Test.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This HTML document display a font that is not my browsers sans-serif font. For me, it is SimSun.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Test.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is normal.

It only affect the font in Google Chrome, I think it may be something to do with CSS property “-webkit-locale”.

Is this normal? How can I set the font for “sans-serif” so that the “lang” attribute doesn’t change the font?

Comment: This seems to affect Firefox and Opera as well.

Comment: font-language-override for the standard (only FF as of writing). -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-language-override -- -webkit-locale https://stackoverflow.com/a/77702242/2344083

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"In Chinese versions of Microsoft Windows XP and older, the default interface typefaces 
are seriffed (MingLiU and SimSun), which is inconsistent with the sans-serif styling 
use in most other (including East Asian) regions of the product. 
Starting in Windows Vista, the default interface typefaces in all regions were changed 
to sans-serif styles, using Microsoft JhengHei in Traditional Chinese environments
and Microsoft YaHei in Simplified Chinese environments."

From Wikipedia.org
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Asian_sans-serif_typeface

Solution:

Use a different font style. 
Chinese and Western users will get different fonts, even though they have the same name.

Alternatively, you could use the :lang(Lang-Code) rule to differentiate the font styles.
Here's an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
        }
        :lang(zh-ch){
            font-family: SimSum-18030,SimHei, serif;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div lang="zh-ch">Chinese font </div>
        <div>Default font.</div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/wCuND/

More information here.

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang.en.php