# meta tag viewport content width and initial scale having issues

Tags: angularjs, html, web-applications, viewport, meta

I am developing a webapp using angularjs. The webapp loads perfectly fine when the mobile device language is set to any except Chinese. I debugged a lot and found the issue that the web app is not loading because of the meta view port tag in the index.html. As soon as I remove the width and initial scale from meta viewport tag, the web app loads successfully in the mobile when the language is set to Chinese. navigator.language = "zh-CN"  May I know the reason why this is creating problem when navigator.language is set to Chinese ? Is there any other alternate solution to make my webapp working?
Having the below meta tag in the index.html, doesn't render my app properly if language is set to Chinese

But if I remove the width and initial-scale, then the app renders properly if language is Chinese.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui"/>.
```

I also tired a sample app, but the issue is observed there as well. Please see below my index.html where you can easily reproduce the issue in any Android phone. I tried in my S3 and also in a S4 device . Please help me on this issue. You can copy the below index.html and load it in your apache server to see the issue. The moment you remove the width and initial-scale from the DOM element, you can see the app loads perfectly.

Please help on this issue

Comment: I am not able to paste the index.html here...any idea how to add it here?

Comment: You don't need to (and cannot) paste the file. Just paste the offending code.

Comment: @ChristianVarga If I use the below meta tag, it doesn't render the app properly .meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui"/>

Where as if i remove the device width and initial scale, it works fine.. This happens only when device language is set to Chinese...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting `initial-scale` and/or `user-scalable`, try combining a `minimum` and `maximum` scale. For example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

You don't need to use `minimal-ui`. Apple dropped support for this in iOS8.

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to set `maximum-scale` nor to set `user-scalable="no"` because it stops people from being able to zoom, which they may need to do.

It would be interesting to see what happens when you remove these and simply use the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

I cannot see how the language would be causing this to happen, but it clearly is occurring, it sounds like a very interesting edge case.

Have you also tried other Chinese related lang settings such as "zh" or "zh-Hans"?

I also wonder if it's related to the font, and thus related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661954/the-lang-attribute-changed-my-font-settings-in-google-chrome%20%22this%20question)?

Comment: No it doesn't work.. I see it working only when I give the below
 <meta name="viewport"
          content="maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui"/>

I have tried zh  , zh-Hans , ko ... It is the same behaviour observed in all these.. and it happens only in Android device

Comment: Hmm, ok, fair enough. What browser on the Android device are you trying it on

Comment: I am trying it in Google Chrome.. tried in S3 , S4 device... Not sure is there any dependency on this device language.. For every other language, the app loads perfect.....Anything to do with styles ? I hope it shouldn't matter

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with fonts?

Comment: But how font is related when the device language is changed ? and that too only for chinese or korean ?

Comment: According to the Stackoverflow question I linked to above, Windows uses a different font for such languages, so I was just wondering if Android did too. It was just a suggestion to perhaps pursue.

Comment: I even tried by changing the font as "SimSum-18030,SimHei, serif" .. But still no help..I can see the same issue... Is there anyway i can share my index.html with you ?

Comment: Yeah you can email it to me, ian at iandevlin dot com.

Comment: Is it that i need to rewrite the whole styling just for Chinese language ? This is really bad...Does this issue has no other solution at all ?

Comment: After again debugging, i found that issue is with "initial-scale" . If initial-scale is set to 1.0 , it doesn't render properly, but if set to 0 , then it loads successfully.. May I know why is this happening ?
<meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no/>

Comment: Google Chrome always set a minimum font size of 12pt for Chinese. This is the reason of the issue. How can it be fixed ? Please help

Comment: Please see the below links >:
https://www.fyianlai.com/2012/01/google-chrome-minimum-font-size-issue/
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=14851