# why it shows different font for different language?

Tags: html, fonts

I have following code snippet.
 It displays different fonts for different language.
The combinations vary on different browsers and on different OS. e.g. on some browser it shows same font for all `<code>` elements/tags.
I have not changed any browser settings.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> different font </title>
  <code lang="en">int i = 0;</code><br>
  <code lang="ru">int i = 0;</code><br>
  <code lang="ja">int i = 0;</code><br>

  <div lang="en">font family</div>
  <div lang="ru">font family</div>
  <div lang="ja">font family</div>
</html>
```

Following is the screenshot on my system. Output may differ on your system.

[image: The screenshot]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661954/the-lang-attribute-changed-my-font-settings-in-google-chrome

Comment: This is happening in IpadOs as well.

Comment: Note that the `<br>` and `<meta>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Comment: What is the default monospace font in those browsers?

Comment: @Rob In the screenshot it's `Consolas` on Chrome and Edge on windows 10. `Consolas` is the default on windows 10, in chrome and edge.

Comment: I meant what is the browser setting? In the config.

Comment: In both the browser its `Consolas` by default. I haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently the browsers you have tried have different default font settings for different languages. If you specify Russian as the language, the browser may be expecting Cyrillic script characters rather than Latin script, and select a different default font for that reason. If you specify Japanese as the language, then it expects kana or kanji characters and will almost certainly select a different default font.